# How to embed an OR-function into a IF(LEFT(CELL())) function?

Tags: excel

I am trying to concatenate a column which has blank values, number values, letter values, and dates, with another column. To sort the dates I am using a `=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",B2))=("G"),"Date","Invalid")`, but the cell function outputs dates with G and D, so I am trying to have an OR-function that allows for both "G" and "D" to be accepted.

```
=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",B2))=("G"),"Date","Invalid")
```

I've tried placing OR at many different spots within the formula and can't get it to work, sometimes thinking I get it but it returns #VALUE

Comment: Did you try the Help for the OR() function at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(CELL("format",B2),1)="G",
       LEFT(CELL("format",B2),1)="D"),"Date","Invalid")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array constant:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(CELL("format",B2))={"G","D"}),"Date","Invalid")
```